# What is output for foo.x

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence

```
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

what is output for foo.x.
My thought is evaluation from right to left
so it is equal to

```
foo = {n:2};
foo.x = foo
```

so it will be

```
{
    n: 1
    x: {n: 2}
}
```

But it is not, it is undefined? I am get confused, looking for an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. See the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1):

> Simple Assignment ( = )
>
> The production AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LeftHandSideExpression.
> 2. Let rref be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.
> 3. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 4. Throw a SyntaxError exception if (...unimportant)
> 5. Call PutValue(lref, rval).
> 6. Return rval.

In short, when the interpreter sees `x = <expression>`, or `x.prop = <expression>`, it first identifies what to assign to - that is, the LeftHandSideExpression. Then, *after* evaluating the right-hand side (the AssignmentExpression) to a value, it assigns the value to what was *initially* identified as the LeftHandSideExpression. So, with

```
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};
```

`foo.x` mutates the *original* `foo` object, not the reassigned `foo = {n: 2}` object, so after the `foo.x = foo = {n: 2}` line, `foo` refers to the new `{n: 2}`, which is never mutated.

You can see how `bar`, which references the same object in memory as the original `foo`, gets mutated:

```js
var foo = {n: 1};
var bar = foo;
foo.x = foo = {n: 2};

console.log(bar);
```